# How to customize the woocommerce 'featured products' widget

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, elementor

Woo commerce widgets are awesome but come with limitation of custom styling.
I'm tired of trying,somebody help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Kindly elaborate on your particular issue or offer more details to clearly outline what assistance you require. The current description makes it challenging to pinpoint the precise nature of your inquiry. *The best practice is to post codes.*

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean customize?

Are you looking to style it with CSS or looking to do something involving what items show?